# Is it proper to say you equivocate on a word?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, verbs, prepositions

I have heard or read several times a sentence similar to: “he equivocated on the word progressive.” I think it pops up mostly in debate/ polemical settings.

I cannot conceptually grasp how ‘on’ is functioning in the sentence; I don’t see what it adds to the overall meaning and how adding ‘on’ brings any further clarity. On the contrary, it’s confusing to me.

To say one equivocates on something sounds like they are doing equivocating while standing or sitting on top of the word. Why not just say: “you equivocated the word progress”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't *equivocate something* because [equivocate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equivocate) is an [intransitive](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/intransitive) verb - it doesn't take a direct object.

When you say that someone equivocates on something, the word "on" carries the sense of the word "about":

> **on** *preposition*
>   Having (the thing mentioned) as a topic; about.
>   ‘A very interesting conversation on language and writing ensued.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/on)

So it's possible to equivocate on a topic. As for the question in your title, equivocating "on a word" tends to carry the notion of equivocating on the choice or appropriateness etc of the word.

Here are a few published instances of the collocation "equivocate on". Note "*equivocate on the word 'utility'*" in the third example below:

- Bourdieu and Wacquant (1992) seem to equivocate on this point.
  [- A Theory of Fields by Neil Fligstein, Doug McAdam](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=tHLZcWC7HLAC&pg=PT230&dq=%22equivocate%20on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3pMzft9XcAhVD7WEKHUoYAUwQ6AEISTAG#v=onepage&q=%22equivocate%20on%22&f=false)
- Before President Wilson acquiesced to his generals' western strategy, which Pershing believed would result in an American victory in 1919, Lloyd George began to equivocate on his policy of the "knock-out blow."
  [- Trial by Friendship, by David R. Woodward](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=v6QfBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA99&dq=%22equivocate%20on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3pMzft9XcAhVD7WEKHUoYAUwQ6AEIUDAH#v=onepage&q=%22equivocate%20on%22&f=false)
- One mistaken way to link welfare and preference is to equivocate on the word 'utility', ....
  [- Development Dilemmas by Melvin Ayogu, Don Ross](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=X-d-AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA43&dq=%22equivocate%20on%20the%20word%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIg9LWudXcAhXXdN4KHYpvD1IQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22equivocate%20on%20the%20word%22&f=false)